# Azure Data Factory Sink as parquet when JSON source has desired values as key

Tags: json, azure-data-factory, parquet

I am using a Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory. The Source calls an API request and a JSON response is returned. The user ids and number of users vary in different API calls.

JSON response example:

```
{
    "rates": {
        "account-default": "0.00",
        "project-default": "0.00",
        "users": {
            "5405": {
                "defaultRate": "0.00",
                "rate": "0.00",
                "source": "direct"
            },
            "5378": {
                "defaultRate": "33.00",
                "rate": "33.00",
                "source": "direct"
            },
            "5454": {
                "defaultRate": "0.00",
                "rate": "0.00",
                "source": "direct"
            },
            "5447": {
                "defaultRate": "0.00",
                "rate": "0.00",
                "source": "direct"
            }
        }
    },
    "STATUS": "OK"
}
```

I want to Sink it directly as parquet saving information of "user_id" and "rate". The problem here is that the user ids (5405, 5378, 5454, 5447) are keys in the JSON response, which impedes me from using Collection reference in Mapping.

[image: screenshot of imported schema in ADF]

The core issue here is that I don't want to Sink as JSON then work with JSON or convert it to parquet later. I want to directly Sink it as parquet.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I've tried using Collection reference in Mapping, but cannot achieve it.

Comment: To get the required output from a JSON like above, you need to use some operations like loop or conditions and only within Copy activity you cannot do the operations like that. The possible solution can be get the JSON and first get the list of keys and convert it to parquet later.

Answer (score 0):

As keys in the JSON are dynamic, using copy activity it might not be possible to achieve your requirement.

You can try ADF **Dataflow** to get the desired output from the above JSON. **But this will work only for the above kind of desired output.**

Set the source with your API request, import the projection and follow the below steps.

After the source, take a `Select` transformation and extract the `keys` as columns from the `users` using Rule based mapping like below.

[image]

Then, take a `derivedColumn` transformation and use the Column pattern with below expression.

```
toDecimal(split(split(replace(toString($$),' ',''),'"rate":"')[2],'"')[1])
```

[image]

This will give the dynamic keys as columns and their respective `rate` as row values.

[image]

Now, take a branch from this transformation and create a `cols_arr` array using **derivedColumn** transformation with below expression.

```
map(columnNames(),toInteger(#item))
```

[image]

In the **other branch**, create a `rates_arr` array using **derivedColumn** transformation with below expression.

```
map(split(concatWS(',', toString(columns())),','),toDecimal(#item))
```

[image]

Use `Select` transformation on these to get only the required array columns.

[image]

Do the same for the **other branch** for the `rates_arr` column.

Then, use `flatten` transformation on these to flatten the array columns.

[image]

Similarly, flatten the same for the **other branch** for the `rates_arr` column.

Now, both will have the required columns. So, we need to combine these columns. To do that, take `SurrogateKey` transformation on both and create a `key` column for both(key name should be same).

[image]

Add the `SurrogateKey` transformation for the other branch as well.

Then, **join these two transformations** using both `key` columns like below.

[image]z

Remove the extra `key` column after this using select transformation and it will give the desired output like below.

[image]

After this, add a sink transformation with your target parquet dataset and execute the dataflow from the pipeline. The expected data will be copied to the parquet file.

**This is the Dataflow Code for your reference:**

```
source(output(
        rates as ({account-default} as string, {project-default} as string, users as ({5378} as (defaultRate as string, rate as string, source as string), {5405} as (defaultRate as string, rate as string, source as string), {5447} as (defaultRate as string, rate as string, source as string), {5454} as (defaultRate as string, rate as string, source as string))),
        STATUS as string
    ),
    allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    ignoreNoFilesFound: false,
    documentForm: 'singleDocument') ~> source1
source1 select(mapColumn(
        each(rates.users,match(true()))
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1
select1 derive(each(match(true()), $$ = toDecimal(split(split(replace(toString($$),' ',''),'"rate":"')[2],'"')[1]))) ~> GetColsAndRates
GetColsAndRates derive(rates_arr = map(split(concatWS(',', toString(columns())),','),toDecimal(#item))) ~> RatesArray
GetColsAndRates derive(cols_arr = map(columnNames(),toInteger(#item))) ~> ColumnsArray
ColumnsArray select(mapColumn(
        each(match(name=='cols_arr'))
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> selectColsArr
RatesArray select(mapColumn(
        each(match(name=='rates_arr'))
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> selectRatesArr
flatten1 keyGenerate(output(key as long),
    startAt: 1L,
    stepValue: 1L) ~> surrogateKey1
selectColsArr foldDown(unroll(cols_arr),
    mapColumn(
        cols_arr
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: false,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: false) ~> flatten1
selectRatesArr foldDown(unroll(rates_arr),
    mapColumn(
        rates_arr
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: false,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: false) ~> flatten2
flatten2 keyGenerate(output(key as long),
    startAt: 1L,
    stepValue: 1L) ~> surrogateKey2
surrogateKey1, surrogateKey2 join(surrogateKey1@key == surrogateKey2@key,
    joinType:'inner',
    matchType:'exact',
    ignoreSpaces: false,
    broadcast: 'auto')~> join1
join1 select(mapColumn(
        cols_arr,
        rates_arr
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select2
```